# How to return parameter values from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to return my parameter values. I am trying to get a value that I can use throughout the rest of my program but cannot seem to figure out how to obtain it. Here is what I am doing (in VB.net). The code that I have tried but is not returning any value is the very last line. (I know I'm going to have to declare it publicly and out of this sub to pass it between forms, but for now I'm just trying to get this value) And ideas??

Thanks!!

```
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(my connection here...)
    Dim cmdUpdate, cmdInsert As SqlCommand
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("procedureName", cnn)
    Try

        Number = txtIncidentNumberUseOfForce.Text
        cmdInsert = New SqlCommand("procUseOfForce", cnn)


        With cmdInsert
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .Parameters.Add("@Height", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 10, "Height")
            .Parameters.Add("@Weight", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 10, "Weight")
            .Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "LastName")
            .Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "FirstName")
            .Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "MiddleName")
            .Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Sex")
            .Parameters.Add("@Race", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Race")
            .Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, "DateOfBirth")
            .Parameters.Add("@FormID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "FormID").Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
            .Parameters.Add("@NameID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "NameID").Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput

        End With

        cmdUpdate = cmdInsert.Clone()

                cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@RecordStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5
                cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@RecordStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4


        With adapter
            .UpdateCommand = cmdUpdate
            .InsertCommand = cmdInsert
        End With



        bs.EndEdit()
        newAuditTrail.RecordChanges(ds, "tblName")
        adapter.Update(ds, "tblName")
        Dim DisplayMe As String = String.Empty
        cmdInsert.Parameters("@NameID").Value = DisplayName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example on how to get an InputOutput parameter from your stored procedure:

```
SqlParameter parm= new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
parm.Size=50; 
parm.Direction=ParameterDirection.InputOutput; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
var productName = cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value;
```

Do not forget to declare the parameter @ProductName as input in Stored Procedure, as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetProductName
@ProductName varchar(50) output

AS

SELECT @ProductName = Name FROM Products
```

I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: Good news, it works! Bad news, only partially. My code here shows my stored procedure for my save routine, that handles both the Insert and Update. So inserting your code works on an initial insert, but it empties out the productName value on the update. So that is interesting.

Comment: To solve this problem I was getting, I had to create two separate parameter for each cmdInsert and cmdUpdate. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem bud, we are here to help and be helped. Happy u got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are declaring DisplayName, but let's assume you have.

I also don't see where you are executing cmdInsert, but let's assume you are.

After executing the command, if you are trying to set your DisplayName variable to the value of the output parameter "NameID", then you have the line backwards.

It should be:

```
DisplayName = cmdInsert.Parameters("@NameID").Value
```